# Is Python's C interface faster than JNI?

Tags: java, python

I was reading [What makes JNI calls slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7699020/165103) and I was wondering if Python's C interface is any better than JNI.

I heard that if you want to make certain parts of your python programs faster, or if a certain part of the program was really hurting your program's performance, you write them in C, and make Python call them.

Does the C interface it incur the same costs JNI does? why or why not?

Comment: The CPython implementation is written in C.  It should be obvious that CPython with C extensions would be really efficient.  Does that answer your question?  What more do you need to know?

Comment: @S.Lott, being written in C does not automatically make it faster. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591879/pypy-how-can-it-possibly-beat-cpython

Comment: @Job "make it faster" != "really efficient" (sometimes, but not always)

Comment: Um.  The question was about overheads between JNI and C, right?  Less overhead would be faster, right?  I'm unclear what hair is being split in the comments.  I can't see how CPython + C could even raise a question.  What more information is needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though I don't know a direct answer to your question, I can't resist answering indirectly:

> I heard that if you want to make certain parts of your python programs faster, or if a certain part of the program was really hurting your program's performance, you write them in C, and make Python call them.

As written in [the topmost answer of the SO question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7809300/59279), "slow" here means tens of nanoseconds. If your expensive part (written in C) takes even one microsecond to execute, then the proportional cost of the C/JNI interface is negligible. The cost only comes whenever you *call* the native part (and when the call returns), not *while* the native part is executing. If you keep the number of calls low, then the extra cost is low. That is, don't write tight Python loops that call C functions; do write the loop itself in C and call it from Python.

As another example that the JNI costs are usually negligible: many of JDK's core classes, e.g. most functions in [Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), and ultimately all graphics and I/O functions map to JNI calls under the hood. Regardless, Java is usually considered to be way faster than CPython.